# Polynomial Matings of Unbounded Quadratic Julia Sets

Tags: complex-analysis, quadratics, recreational-mathematics, fractals

I know that quadratic Julia Set matings [are only supposed to work for the connected sets](https://www.emis.de//journals/EM/expmath/volumes/13/13.1/Milnor.pdf), but I got curious and tried to make one using disconnected ones. To my surprise (using the algorithm I learned from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747790)), the results were really spectacular! My animations are shown [here](https://youtu.be/tP-gZAP7JfI), [here](https://youtu.be/m7_6qnabxBw), and [here](https://youtu.be/aJ9k5khI39c?list=PLYUFxbjHkLgbTJNuXluk0OXmZ2QcLIC3a) through different perspectives (all showing the same mating between the $.285+.01i$ and $-.835-.2321i$ Julia Sets).

Unfortunately, I recently realized why these animations had to be ended early: the orbits for both Julia Sets are unbounded (which is probably why matings only work for certain sets). As such, in the first part of the algorithm when I simply iterate the two coordinates (the $p$ and $q$ sets in the "Initialization" part), they diverge to infinity after about 28 iterations (due to my machine's floating-point precision), which messes up the rest of the calculations. However, the animation clearly shows that the mating could have been continued, and so I'd like to figure out a way to accomplish this.

I realize this could be seen as a programming question as an easy solution could simply be to use arbitrary-precision variables to solve this issue. However, I'd like to know if there are any alternative algorithms to the [Thurston Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04177v1.pdf) that avoid these calculations, or perhaps some other magic solution that can accomplish what I seek without quickly diverging to infinity - or at least delay it to a much later iteration.

My project is [here](https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating) to use as testing grounds, if so needed.

**Note:** I tried implementing [robust complex division](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.4539.pdf), but this only saved me a single mating iteration. The orbits diverge much too quickly for this to have any lasting effect.

## Edit

I figured I should post what worked for me anyways, even though it uses a programming solution. I made my own [BigDouble class](https://github.com/Ibrahim9999/Riemann-Mating/blob/master/OpenTK%20Reimann%20Mandlebrot/BigDouble.cs), where the mathematical operations performed between numbers are represented in scientific notation. This effectively allows me to bypass the double-precision limit of [$1.798*10^{308}$](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.maxvalue?view=netcore-3.1) and go up to [$9.99*10^{2,147,483,647}$](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netcore-3.1), all without using slow bignum/infinite-precision arithmetic. Using this, I could now iterate coordinates outside the Mandelbrot Set without running into floating-point limitations (it's not 100% perfect, but it still gets the job done).

Comment: maybe you could represent complex numbers as 3D unit vectors on the Riemann sphere?  not sure how you'd implement all the operations though...

Comment: @Claude That could be an idea, and the operations could definitely be magically implemented, however I think the transition to spherical coordinates might cause a loss in accuracy (unless things end up canceling each other out nicely)